# The animation of the tank’s caterpillars, when you go through the animation, the caterpillars collapse, why?

Tags: animation

I decided to make an animation of the tank’s tracks, the model of the tank is complex and the tracks are also complex. After a large number of attempts to set up the correct physics, nothing happens and everything collapses when the animation starts.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Honestly I think you would get into less trouble by using drivers rather than using a simulation, you can find plenty of resources on the subject on YT

Comment: What kind of technique will be much more difficult to implement than animation of physics? Yes, but there are videos in which a similar technique is realized and the tank really goes. Or did they also use this technique in the form of drivers?